# how to resolve 403 forbidden in 3dwarehouse?

Tags: sketchup

while I am trying to signup on 3dwarehouse it gives me an error of 403 forbidden.
here is the link to the website.
https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/
your help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using google chrome then try to search this link on Mozilla firefox or uinstall google chrome then install it.
Your issue will be resolve by this.